If I use CC-BY-SA art in a work, may I also distribute the work without said art under a different license?
I want to design a board game, but have no art skills to speak of. I would like to distribute this game 2 ways:

Using art that is licensed under CC-BY-SA, and this whole package would obviously have to be licensed under CC-BY-SA.
Without any art, just the text that I have created, under a more permissive license.

Is this allowed?
Would the answer change if it were a stricter share-alike license? Or would it be allowed no matter what, since these distributions are completely separate.

If this question would be more appropriate for the opensource stack exchange, feel free to let me know. I thought not since this isn't about software, but I guess they probably have a lot of experience with copyleft.

Also, be aware, game rules are not protected by copyright.

You only have to follow the CC-BY-SA license for the version of the work that's derived from the third-party artwork.
You're the sole copyright owner of the version that doesn't incorporate the third-party artwork, so you can distribute that version under any valid license you choose.
